# How to disable DRParser Mode from using mobile data?

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, mobile-data

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016, A310F) with Android 7.
I switched off "using mobile data" but every time when I turn on the phone or restart it, the "DRParser Mode" (system application) uses my mobile data.

Screenshots are below:

[image: Screenshot of data usage] [image: Screenshot of data usage] [image: Screenshot of data usage] [image: Screenshot of data usage]

How to block, disable or remove this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two apps that you can use to disable unnecessary packages (and in this case DRParser Mode) .

These are [Package Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ospolice.packagedisablerpro) and [Adhell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getadhell.androidapp). Both apps list out all the apps and services installed on the device and let you disable or enable them with a single tap. Most importantly it’s completely reversible and no root is required.

> Adhell is a Free, Open Source Ad Blocker with **Package Disabler** for
>   Samsung Devices, while Adhell is free while Package Disabler costs a
>   little over $1.

[image]

Acknowledgements

- http://www.androidguys.com/2017/06/30/disable-system-apps-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s8-without-root-using-these-apps/